# CSS - Animating display property

Tags: css

I have a web page that contains five divs. A user can switch between the divs by clicking a next or previous button. If next is clicked, I fade-in the next `div` on top of the existing one and fade-out the existing `div`. Imagine something like flipping through some pictures.

My problem is, I am only animating the opacity property. Because of this, the users cannot interact with some of the elements of the visible `div`. My hunch is that its because there is an invisible `div` on top of it.

```
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; }}
@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; }}

.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:1rem;

    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:1rem;

    animation: fadeOut 0.3s ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Is there a way using CSS, that I could change the `display` property from `inline` to `none` when the `fade-out` animation has completed? I know I could wire up some jQuery. However, that seems kind of clumsy. It seems like there should be a way for me to change an element from visible to hidden after the 0.3s have elapsed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The display property is not animatable, use visibility (visible->hidden) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, opacity will keep the invisible overlaying elements on-top.

Animate `opacity`, but at the same time toggle `visibility` from/to `hidden/visible` allowing interaction with underlying elements once an element is `visibility:hidden`

Also, instead of `relative` since you want a fade-trough effect, `absolute` should best fit your requirements.

Comment: I'm still learning css animation. Its like I have two animations happening at once. First, the fade effect. Second the visibility toggle. How do I add the second animation so that it fires after the first has completed?

Comment: @JQueryMobile can you setup a jsBin demo example so I can take a look at what you have exactly right now and how you're currently applying and triggering your animations?